# Tengo un error en C# Excepción producida: 'System.FormatException' en mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, ms-access

Tengo el error. "La cadena de entradad no tiene el formato  correcto" al momento de tocar el botón para enviar los a la base de datos de access.
private void btnCrearReporte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
    try
    {
        var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NOC_C_.Properties.Settings.old_noc_databaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (OleDbConnection Conector = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            Conector.Open();
            // (fuente_reporte, fecha_incidente, fecha_notificacion, sitio_equipo, evento, tipo_evento, detalle_evento, tipo_trabajo, agente_monitoreo, encargado_ly)
            string query = "INSERT INTO reporte (fuente_reporte, fecha_incidente, fecha_notificacion, sitio_equipo, evento, tipo_evento, detalle_evento, tipo_trabajo, agente_monitoreo, encargado_ly)  VALUES (@fuente_reporte, @fecha_incidente, @fecha_notificacion, @sitio_equipo, @evento, @tipo_evento, @detalle_evento, @tipo_trabajo, @agente_monitoreo,@encargado_ly);";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, Conector);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fuente_reporte", CMBMedioDeReporte.SelectedItem);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_incidente", DateIncidente.Value.ToString("dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_notificacion", DateNotificacion.Value.ToString("dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sitio_equipo", Int32.Parse(CMBEquipoFrm.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@evento", CMBTituloFrm.SelectedItem);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_evento", Int32.Parse(CMBTipoFrm.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detalle_evento", txtDetalle.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_trabajo", CMBTipoDeTrabajo.SelectedItem);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agente_monitoreo", Int32.Parse(CMBAgenteDeMonitoreo.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@encargado_ly", Int32.Parse(CMBEncargadoLYFrm.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: duplicar tu pregunta no va a hacer que alguien encuentre tu problema mas rapido. El sitio no funciona asi